# Pandas: How to calculate number of changes considering previous record

Tags: python, pandas, record, counting

I have a dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 
                  "val":[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]})

    id  val
0    1    0
1    1    1
2    1    1
3    1    0
4    1    1
5    1    0
6    2    0
7    2    1
8    2    0
9    2    1
10   3    0
11   3    0
12   3    0
13   3    1
```

As you can see the ID's are duplicated and I have values alternating between 0 and 1. I'd like to somehow calculate the number of times when values switch from 0 to 1. For example like this:

```
id  val
1    2
2    2
3    1
```

It's not a count of 1, but rather counter number of times val switch for 0-->1 for each ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `diff`

```
df.groupby('id').val.apply(lambda x : sum(x.diff().eq(1)))
Out[306]: 
id
1    2
2    2
3    1
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if I want to find change from 0 to any integer?

Comment: @AnthonySun change to gt(0)

Comment: but gt(0) will also treate 4-->5 for example as a change right? I only wanted to count 0-->+int.

Comment: @AnthonySun then you need sum((x==0)&(x.shift!=0))

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
>>> # To be more exact: (df['val'] == 1) & (df['val'].shift() == 0
>>> df['val'].diff().eq(1).groupby(df['id']).sum().astype(int)

id
1    2
2    2
3    1
```

Generally, I like to avoid `groupby.apply(...)` if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the values are always either `0` or `1`, you need to group by `id` and track when the difference is `1`

```
df.groupby('id')['val'].apply(lambda x: (x - x.shift() == 1).sum()).reset_index()


   id   val
0   1   2
1   2   2
2   3   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['val1'] = df.groupby('id').shift(1)
df['tag']= df.val-df.val1
df['tag']=df['tag'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x==1 else 0)
df[['id','tag']].groupby('id').sum()

    tag
id     
1     2
2     2
3     1
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation in your answer (e.g. leave inline comments).